# Angular: ng-content doesn't render with *ngIf then else

Tags: angular, if-statement, ng-template, ng-content

I want to style the content differently depending on the [id] of the popup-content. 
 Now only the 'then' case of *ngIf renders when the conditions are true.
  If the conditions aren't met, the <ng-content> inside the else case doesn't. 
 Is there something wrong with this code?

1. The if else itself works if I remove the ng-content and replace it with plain text
2. id == 'login-popup' connection works well too

```css
.content {
  background-color: #03448f;
  opacity: 0.72;
}

.content-solid-bkgd {
  background-color: #03448f;
  opacity: 0.92;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf=" id == 'login-popup' || id == 'language-popup'; then lowOpacity; else highOpacity; "></div>

<ng-template #lowOpacity>
  <div [ngClass]="'content'">
    <ng-content select=".popup-content"></ng-content>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #highOpacity>
  <div [ngClass]="'content-solid-bkgd'">
    <ng-content select=".popup-content"></ng-content>
  </div>
</ng-template>
</div>
```

If I type random text between <ng-template> and <div> of the "ELSE" case,
the text gets rendered but not the <ng-content> 
ie:

```html
 <ng-template #highOpacity>
      randomTestingText
        <div [ngClass]="'content-solid-bkgd'">
            <ng-content select=".popup-content"></ng-content>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using ng-content two times to render the same thing, all I can see is a change of class, just use a ternary operator with ngClass to toggle the classes!

```css
.content {
  background-color: #03448f;
  opacity: 0.72;
}

.content-solid-bkgd {
  background-color: #03448f;
  opacity: 0.92;
}
```

```html
<div [ngClass]="id == 'login-popup' || id == 'language-popup' ? 'content' : 'content-solid-bkgd'">

  <ng-content select=".popup-content"></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! What a neat fix :) Totally made my day